# Insert tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables, Order and OrderDetails.

```
Order Table 
 OrderID
 Order_Details_Id
 Date
 Cust_Id


Order Details
 Order_Details_Id
 prod_name
 prod_amt
 OrderID
```

Basically i want to insert several order details in one order table. My issue is i am not quite sure how to set OrderID in the Order table to the OrderID in Order Details in PHP. I have made an attempt at it with no luck, this is what i have so far :

```
$order = "INSERT INTO Order (orderID, cust_id, date)
        VALUES ('$cust_id, '23/11/2017')";
$DBcon->exec($order);

foreach ($prodname as $prodname) {

    foreach ($prodamount as $prodamount) {

        $od = "INSERT INTO Order_Details (OrderDetails_id, prod_name, prod_amt,orderID)
        VALUES ('$prodname' , '$prodamount',orderID(?) )";

    $DBcon->exec($od);

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, i am relatively new to using PHP and SQL!

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`?

Comment: Apologies i forget to mention that, i am using mysqli!

Comment: Whats inside the vars `$prodname` and `$prodamount `

Comment: Your first insert has orderID as a column to insert, but not a value for it.  I assume this is (as pointed out) being set as an auto increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mysqli::$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get last inserted id

```
$DBcon->exec($order);
$orderID = $DBcon->insert_id;
```

Now use this varibale instead of `orderID(?)` in your Second INSERTcode.

Comment: That would be inline to what i am looking for, i will try it out thanks

Comment: Just tested it out, works perfectly thanks for your answer

Comment: @GrandeurH  glad to help you :):)